# Change file icons in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, icons

The Folder Options dialog in Windows XP Explorer had a File Types tab that allowed one to change a file type's icon. Windows 7 doesn't have this. Is there a way to change file icons without changing its default application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend [**Default Programs Editor**](http://defaultprogramseditor.com) for this task- it's designed for Windows 7 and makes it really easy to edit that kind of stuff.

Check it out:

[image: Using Default Programs Editor to change file type icons in windows 7]

Comment: I don't get it, why on the effin earth did Microsoft remove this exsiting feature!?

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to [a tutorial on how to use FileTypesMan to change file icons](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12383/change-a-file-types-icon-in-windows-7/), or you can [manually edit the registry](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/change-file-type-icon-windows-7-and-vista/).

(FileTypesMan can be downloaded [here](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html).)